# how to start Spring batch module in spring xd

Tags: spring-xd

I have a spring boot  module which downloads file from s3 and put in local directory.I am using

```
mvn spring-boot:run or
java -jar myspringboot.jar MySpringBoot.class
```

Now i want  to upload this as a module in xd ?How to upload it and how to start my spring boot application?Or should i convert to job and launch the job?
I understand that I should create a module package into `uber.jar` and deploy it as module.Since this module is spring boot jar will it start when i start xd?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you could as well wrap the Spring Boot class into a Spring Batch job and execute it as part of a data load.

Other option is to extract the S3 download routine and convert it into a Spring Batch job. Then use this job directly in Spring XD or launch it as a Spring Boot application. (for more follow this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)

As a last alternative I see launching the Spring Boot application as a part of a Spring XD stream. Pretty much like this:

```
trigger --fixedDelay=3600 > shell --command='java -jar myspringboot.jar MySpringBoot.class'
```